# uwp image binding not working with x:Bind

Tags: c#, image, xaml, binding, uwp-xaml

I am trying to bind an imageSource within an ellipse on my XAML page to an ImageSource property in my ViewModel, as I am using MVVM approach in my project. I can confirm by breakpoints that the property in c# gets the image and gets filled, but for some odd reason it doesn't show up in XAML, and when I analyze source property with livepropertyExplorer in the blend, the source in ImageSource shows "0". Here is my code.

**XAML**

```
<Ellipse x:Name="ProfileImage" Style="{StaticResource ProfilePicStyle}">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Banner, Mode=OneWay}" 
                    Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public AllVideosViewModel() : base()
    {
        //var bit = new BitmapImage();
        //bit.UriSource = (new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Storelogo.png"));
        //Banner = bit;
        //Above 3 lines were test code and it works perfect and binding works in this case, but I want the binding as coded in the Initialize method below, because I want that image to bind with the thumbnails of the collection.
        Initialize();
    }
private async void Initialize()
    {
        var VideoFiles = (await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName)) as IEnumerable<StorageFile>;

        foreach (var file in VideoFiles)
        {
            <...some code to fill grid view on the same XAML page which works perfect...>
            Banner = await FileHelper.GetDisplay(file);//this method returns Image just fine because I am using the same method to display thumbnails on the same XAML page which work fine.
        }

    }
```

**Thanks in advance.**

**UPDATE Sample project**

[sample project to test on github](https://github.com/touseefbsb/ThumbnailTest.git)

Comment: "this method returns Image ...". Actually, it should return an ImageSource (or a derived type like BitmapImage). What is the type of the Banner property?

Comment: the type of banner property is ImageSource and the method GetDisplay returns BitmapImage

Comment: method is fine , as I specified that I am using the same method to fill my gridview with thumbnails on the very same page

Comment: Change it to a local image, does it work?

Comment: yes as I mentioned in the code if I bind it to an image in asset folder then it works fine @Justin XL

Comment: Sorry missed that. Any chance you could provide a sample project with the issue?

Comment: here you go please test it and let me know :) thanks https://github.com/touseefbsb/ThumbnailTest.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things I have noticed in your code.

1. Your `MainViewModel` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and your `Banner` property needs to raise the property changed event. This is why you don't see any image displayed on the UI.
2. You should use `await bit.SetSourceAsync()` instead of `bit.SetSourceAsync()` as it doesn't block the UI thread.
3. Since you are not using the `Image` control but the `ImageBrush` directly, you should set the decode size to how much you need so you don't waste memory there. Note the `Image` control does this for you automatically.

   ```
       bit = new BitmapImage
       {
           DecodePixelWidth = 48,
           DecodePixelHeight = 48
       };
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: why do I need to provide Inotify property ? doesn't x:Bind one way supposed to do this automatically? I mean if not then wht is function of X:Bind with Mode "oneway" ?

Comment: No... x:Bind only gives you compile time binding which gives you better performance over traditional bindings. Nothing else is changed. x:Bind to function with oneway is new in anniversary update. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#functions-in-binding-paths

Comment: You still need properties with INotifyPropertyChanged when they are used as params in function binding, otherwise how would it know when to reevaluate?

Comment: in this case I am directly binding to a property in the viewmodel, yes you solution works with Inotify property implemented but it is still unclear to me that what is function of oneway, if we still need to implement Inotify, and yeah the minimum target on my project is Anniversay Update

Comment: I am changing the value of that specific property within a function, is that why I need Inotify?

Comment: I am confused, where is this function you are talking about? I only see you are using a **property** (i.e. `Banner`) with x:Bind in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146034/discussion-between-touseef-and-justin-xl).